# Drive API no email sent after change ownership

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-drive-api

I have done an application that changes the ownership on a spreadsheet, after having created it.

Until few days ago, the user who received the ownership of the file, was able to receive also an email for the change ownership from Google.

Now Google is not sending anymore the notification email, even if I set to true the "sendNotificationEmail" parameter.

I'm using Drive APIs version v3-rev173-1.25.0.

Do you have any idea of what is happening?

Thanks!